# Angular 2 - Navigate without showing data on url

Tags: angular

In Angular 2, is there a way to navigate and pass data that is not shown in the URL?

I want to create a component that receives a complex object, but do not want this to be displayed in the URL.

Thanks!

Comment: Set the data on a service that is injected into the component?

Comment: There is a simpler way? I don´t want to make a service class just for that. I have to do a class every time you want to hide the parameters??

Comment: No. The router passes dynamic data via the URL. You could serialize and  encode your object in the URL, but you'd need to be careful of any characters not allowed in URL strings. 

A shared service is the recommended way, and cleanest.

Comment: You can also either save it in cookies, local storage or service. If you think one of them is an option.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: Thanks Günter but I need to navigate, not only pass data trough components. I think the only way is via services like @HeyStatan says.

Answer (score 6):

Only to support new readers who are using new versions of angular, in angular 7.2 and above you can use state to pass data objects dynamically without showing in url.

```
this.router.navigate(['/some-route'], {state: {data: {...}}});
```

then you can read state like:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.state = this.activatedRoute.paramMap
        .pipe(map(() => window.history.state));}
```

Comment: skiplocations worked for me today.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `navigate` method, then add `skipLocationChange` like this:

```
this.router.navigate(['/your-path'], { skipLocationChange: true });
```

If you're using `routerLink`, use it as an attribute like this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/your-path']" skipLocationChange></a>
```

Please bear in mind that if you use `skipLocationChange`, the route in the browser won't be updated after navigating to the new route, so if the user hits back in the browser he'll be sent to the path before the first path. I haven't found a solution for this yet.

Answer (score 3):

You can use below function to pass parameters:

```
this.router.navigate(['/somePage'], {queryParams: {'name': 'Emon'}, skipLocationChange: true});
```

This works for me!

Comment: How to access that `name` value in Component?

Comment: Hi @dev, You can use [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute). There is a function called  `queryParams`.
For Example:
`this.activeRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params =>{
this.userName= params['name'];});`

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done..
Below is an example from this [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html).

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'hero/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent },
  { path: 'crisis-center', component: CrisisCenterComponent },
  {
    path: 'heroes',
    component: HeroListComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Heroes List'
    }
  },
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

In this example we are passing an object to 'heroes' path which will not be displayed in url.Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank´s for the answer, but I need to define de data when the user make some action instead when I define de Routes.

Comment: I am not sure , but we can always set appRoutes.path.data.. dynamically